# Chain of Responsibility in the game of Hangman

Tags: java, design-patterns

I tried to do the Hangman Refactoring Kata for the piece of code over here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0MeoFTj6DU

This is how the initial code looks like after first set of refactorings (i.e. after refactoring + adding tests) - https://github.com/yadavvi91/hangman-kata/blob/f9db05fe38516d2fc23f2352c97dcfdf900d7459/src/main/java/org/yadavvi/ConsoleGame.java

```java
public class ConsoleGame implements Game {

    @Override
    public void play() {
        String word = dictionary.selectWord();
        String matched = word;
        String lettersUsed = "";
        String guesses = repeat("_ ", word.length());
        int badGuessCount = 0;
        while (badGuessCount < 6 && !matched.equals(repeat("_", word.length()))) {
            ui.showGallows(badGuessCount);
            ui.showGuesses(guesses);
            ui.showNextGuessPrompt();
            char guess = ui.getGuess();

            if (lettersUsed.indexOf(guess) >= 0) {
                ui.showAlreadyGuessed(guesses);
            } else {
                lettersUsed += guess;
                if (matched.indexOf(guess) >= 0) {
                    String newGuesses = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
                        if (word.charAt(i) == guess) {
                            newGuesses += guess + " ";
                        } else {
                            newGuesses += mid(guesses, i * 2, 2);
                        }
                    }
                    guesses = newGuesses;
                    matched = matched.replace(guess, '_');
                } else {
                    ++badGuessCount;
                    if (badGuessCount == 6) {
                        ui.showGallows(badGuessCount);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (matched.equals(repeat("_", word.length()))) {
                ui.showGallows(badGuessCount);
                ui.showGuesses(guesses);
                ui.showYouWon();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

After a number of refactorings, I made the code use "Chain of Responsibility" pattern like so - https://github.com/yadavvi91/hangman-kata/blob/master/src/main/java/org/yadavvi/ConsoleGame.java

```java
package org.yadavvi;

public class ConsoleGame implements Game {

    private final Provider provider;

    public ConsoleGame(UI ui, Dictionary dictionary) {
        ....
        this.provider = new AlreadyGuessedProvider(new CorrectGuessProvider(new BadGuessProvider()));
    }

    @Override
    public void play() {
        while (areBadGuessesValid() && !isAMatch(word, matched)) {
            ui.showGallows(badGuessCount);
            ui.showGuesses(guesses);
            ui.showNextGuessPrompt();
            char guess = ui.getGuess();

            provider.doSomething(guess);
        }
        // is word correctly guessed
        if (isAMatch(word, matched)) {
            ui.showGallows(badGuessCount);
            ui.showGuesses(guesses);
            ui.showYouWon();
        }
        // is word incorrectly guessed
        if (!areBadGuessesValid()) {
            ui.showGallows(badGuessCount);
        }
    }

     private String getNewGuesses(char guess) {
        String newGuesses = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == guess) {
                newGuesses += guess + " ";
            } else {
                newGuesses += mid(guesses, i * 2, 2);
            }
        }
        return newGuesses;
    }

    private boolean areBadGuessesValid() {
        return badGuessCount < 6;
    }

    private boolean isAlreadyGuessed(char guess) {
        return lettersUsed.indexOf(guess) >= 0;
    }

    private boolean isGuessACharInWord(char guess) {
        return matched.indexOf(guess) >= 0;
    }

    private boolean isAMatch(String word, String matched) {
        return matched.equals(repeat("_", word.length()));
    }

    interface Provider {
        void doSomething(char guess);
    }

    class AlreadyGuessedProvider implements Provider {
        Provider next;

        AlreadyGuessedProvider(Provider next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public void doSomething(char guess) {
            if (isAlreadyGuessed(guess)) {
                ui.showAlreadyGuessed(guesses);
            } else {
                next.doSomething(guess);
            }
        }
    }

    class CorrectGuessProvider implements Provider {
        Provider next;

        CorrectGuessProvider(Provider next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public void doSomething(char guess) {
            if (isGuessACharInWord(guess)) {
                lettersUsed += guess;
                guesses = getNewGuesses(guess);
                matched = matched.replace(guess, '_');
            } else {
                next.doSomething(guess);
            }
        }
    }

    class BadGuessProvider implements Provider {
        @Override
        public void doSomething(char guess) {
            lettersUsed += guess;
            badGuessCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like some feedback on the implementation or an alternate implementation if this one isn't correct/good enough.

---

There is another thing that I wanted some help with, in the method below, show we prefer `condition-check-and-break` or `break/no-break check-condition-outside loop`

- Condition Check and `break`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream in = System.in;
    PrintStream out = System.out;

    String word = selectWord();

    String matched = word;
    String lettersUsed = "";
    String guesses = repeat("_ ", word.length());
    int badGuessCount = 0;
    while (badGuessCount < 6 && !matched.equals(repeat("_", word.length()))) {
        showGallows(badGuessCount, out);
        showGuesses(guesses, out);
        showNextGuessPrompt(out);
        char guess = getGuess(in);

        if (lettersUsed.indexOf(guess) >= 0) {
            showAlreadyGuessed(guesses, out);
        } else {
            lettersUsed += guess;
            if (matched.indexOf(guess) >= 0) {
                String newGuesses = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
                    if (word.charAt(i) == guess) {
                        newGuesses += guess + " ";
                    } else {
                        newGuesses += mid(guesses, i*2, 2);
                    }
                }
                guesses = newGuesses;
                matched = matched.replace(guess, '_');
                if (matched.equals(repeat("_", word.length()))) {
                    showGallows(badGuessCount, out);
                    showGuesses(guesses, out);
                    showYouWon(out);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                ++badGuessCount;
                if (badGuessCount == 6) {
                    showGallows(badGuessCount, out);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- `break`/no-`break` Check condition outside loop

````java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream in = System.in;
    PrintStream out = System.out;

    String word = selectWord();

    String matched = word;
    String lettersUsed = "";
    String guesses = repeat("_ ", word.length());
    int badGuessCount = 0;
    while (badGuessCount < 6 && !matched.equals(repeat("_", word.length()))) {
        showGallows(badGuessCount, out);
        showGuesses(guesses, out);
        showNextGuessPrompt(out);
        char guess = getGuess(in);

        if (lettersUsed.indexOf(guess) >= 0) {
            showAlreadyGuessed(guesses, out);
        } else {
            lettersUsed += guess;
            if (matched.indexOf(guess) >= 0) {
                String newGuesses = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
                    if (word.charAt(i) == guess) {
                        newGuesses += guess + " ";
                    } else {
                        newGuesses += mid(guesses, i*2, 2);
                    }
                }
                guesses = newGuesses;
                matched = matched.replace(guess, '_');
            } else {
                ++badGuessCount;
            }
        }
    }
    if (matched.equals(repeat("_", word.length()))) {
        showGallows(badGuessCount, out);
        showGuesses(guesses, out);
        showYouWon(out);
    }
    if (badGuessCount == 6) {
        showGallows(badGuessCount, out);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Both pieces of code are incomplete. E.g. there is no declaration of `isGuessACharInWord` in the second piece. Please update the question with the working version of the code. Also, what is the purpose of using chain-of-responsibility here? Seems to only make the code longer. If I missed any benefits, please, specify what they are in the question.

Comment: There is a github link right there. Anyways, updated the question with `isGuessACharInWord` as well.

Comment: This is a refactoring kata where one has to use OO Design Patterns during the refactoring. If Chain of Responsibility isn't the right fit, please suggest an alternative.

Comment: I personally don't mind checking the github, but there's a site rule that all code required for the review must be present in the question (the author may decide to delete the github repo 5 years later and the whole question will become invalid). As for design patterns, there is the KISS principle - "keep it simple, stupid". Don't overcomplicate what is already concise and working.

Comment: I know this is a contrived example but this was a part of an assignment I had received to do OOP refactoring katas.

There is this place where we have a number of refactoring code katas - https://kata-log.rocks/refactoring